# What is the initial size of Array in HashMap Architecture?

Tags: java, hashmap

I think `HashMap`'s internal buckets use an array to store values based on keys as in the below screenshot.

[image: array in HashMap]

So, is the initial size of the array 16? Later if the size increases the `HashMap` internally rehashes everything? If not then what is the initial size of the array in a `HashMap`.

Also please confirm whether it uses an array or any other data structure like `ArrayList`?

Comment: It's in [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#HashMap--): "*Constructs an empty HashMap with the default initial capacity (16) and the default load factor (0.75).*"

Comment: I think that maps and arrays are generally distinct concepts.  Also, the linked list reference in your diagram isn't strictly correct in Java 8.  Java 8 uses a balanced tree to handle collisions.

Comment: If you want to know exactly how it works, then lookup the source code of class `java.util.HashMap`, you can find it in `src.zip` in your JDK installation directory.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Yes Java 8 uses Red-Black trees. I need this in older versions.

Comment: @assylias, Thanks for this. I know that the initial capacity is 16 and also about the load factor. I just want to know whether array size is 16?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The tree is used only after a threshold, to handle pathological cases. Linked list of colliding entries is the initial strategy.

Comment: please have a look into a counter question on this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40849888/a-hashmap-with-default-capacity-16-can-contain-more-than-11-16-objectsk-v-with ...many thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 3):

> does it mean that the initial size of the Array is 16

This is the default in the OpenJDK/OracleJDK. You can set it higher or lower.

> later if size increases the HashMap internally rehashes to new size?

When the load factor is reached it resizes and rearranges the hashed elements/keys

> If not then what is the initial size of Array in HashMap

If you set it, the next power of two is used.

> whether it uses Array or any other data structure like ArrayList

It uses an array and an additional data structure to handle collisions.

> Java 8 uses a balanced tree to handle collisions

If the keys are Comparable e.g. String, any Number, a tree is used, otherwise a list is used.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So should I conclude with this statement " HashMap uses Array & the size of that array initially is 16"- java 7 older versions. I'm aware of the load factor and rehashing but got confused with the statement that "Initial size of HashMap is 16". Hence, the length of array is the actual size of hashMap- is this correct? I think yes.

Comment: A tree is only used when the hash chain is long enough (>= 8 entries)

Comment: @RohitGaikwad the initial capacity is 16 by default which allows up to 11 entries before resizing.  The initial size () is always 0.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, Can you please have a look into a counter question on this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40849888/a-hashmap-with-default-capacity-16-can-contain-more-than-11-16-objectsk-v-with  ...thanks.

Answer (score 0):

from Oracle docs the,

HashMap() Constructs an empty HashMap with the default initial capacity (16) and the default load factor of 0.75

Comment: the question is about size of array in hashmap & not about the hashmap default size

Comment: as HashMap is consist of key,value pairs where keys are unique and values consist of array of value, from this we can conclude its initial size as 16.